# Flower UI does not show celery workers and Tasks

Tags: python, django, celery, djcelery, flower

I have installed flower for my django app using `pip install flower`. I start it using the command `./manage.py celery flower --port=5555`. I get the following output after that.

```
[I 150324 16:40:47 command:106] Visit me at http://localhost:5555
[I 150324 16:40:47 command:107] Broker: django://localhost//
[E 150324 16:40:47 state:52] Dashboard and worker management commands are not available for 'sql' transport
[I 150324 16:40:47 mixins:225] Connected to django://localhost//
```

However I am not able to see any tasks and workers in the UI. Any pointers please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using django db as a broker. Flower doesn't support sql transport.